Java package import issue
I am tring to import the package as I am tring to learn the java. I am facing issue while importing the class from different package.
package one;
public class Abhi{
    public void fun(){
        System.out.println("Fun function from Abhi class");
    }
}


package two;
import one.Abhi;
public class World {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("World Class Start");
        World obj = new World();
        obj.fun();
    }
}

I am facing the issue while I am trying to import java package class which is a public class as well as public function from the package giving me the error when I am compiling it in VS code. Which I don't understand the reason because I believe code is correct. Please help.
error image 

Please give the error in the question itself in txt form. Avoid pointing to images using links.

(1) Your World Class does not have the fun method, only Abhi has the fun method. (2) If you want to use Abhi's fun method, you should write: Abhi obj = new Abhi(); , obj.fun(); 

have you checked the formatting of your question? Hint: the backticks must be alone on a single line. Also consider Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You have imported the package correctly. The problem relies on your object.
The function "fun()" is declared on the class "Abhi", so the object that can call "fun()" needs to be an Abhi, not World.
Your main should look like this:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Abhi obj = new Abhi();
    obj.fun();
}


This is not working because there is no fun method in the World class. To call the fun method, you should do it like this:
package two;
import one.Abhi;

public class World {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("World Class Start");
        Abhi obj = new Abhi();
        obj.fun();
    }
}

